# jQuery - Finding next Div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the next div after an input button and toggle it.

What am I doing wrong?

JS:

```
$(".showNextExperience").click(function() {
    $(".experience").show();
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="showNextExperience" >
<div class="experience">Experience 1</div>

<input class="showNextExperience">
<div class="experience">Experience 2</div>

<input class="showNextExperience">
<div class="experience">Experience 3</div>

<input class="showNextExperience" >
<div class="experience">Experience 4</div>
```

Okay, this DOES NOT work ---

```
$(".showExperience").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".experience").toggle();
});

<table class="data">
    <tr class="tableHead">
        <td></td>
        <td width="50" align="right"><input type="button" class="showExperience" value="show"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="experience">2</div>
```

When I move the input button just above the DIV it works just fine.

```
$(".showExperience").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".experience").toggle();
});

<input type="button" class="showExperience" value="show">
<div class="experience">2</div>
```

Can you explain that?

Comment: As a late answer to your question why your button inside the table didn't work. Because `next('showExperience ')` searches for the next sibling with that class, but your button has 0 siblings to search from. And may I add that that input tag never closes (dirty coding) and above is an empty td (very dirty coding), may I ask what the point of the whole table was, if it really only contains a single button? >_<

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply:

```
$(".showNextExperience").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".experience").toggle();
});
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
- http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: This is the correct answer and exactly what I have been doing. It doesn't work for me though. Something is wrong in my table. When the input button is outside of the table, it works fine. When I cut/past that same button into a table, it stops working.  Thanks!

Comment: Because `.next` only selects the *very next sibling*. In the case of a table element, you will probably need to traverse up to the parent row, find the next row, and find the `.experience` div within the row. DOM structure is important! e.g. `$(this).closest("tr").next().find(".experience").toggle()`

Comment: You are 100%!!! That's an ugly solution though. My div is after the table. Do I have to go parent().parent().parent().next("div.experience")? or something like that? I can't get that to work either.

Comment: Sorry to comment here, but this answer, even though is the correct answer for the problem, is not actually answering the header question: How to find next div. `.next([selector])` retrieves the next element only if it matches the selector, and you are assuming, I believe, that `.next([selector])` retrieves the next element that matches the selector. Not quite the same

Answer (score 6):

```
$(".showNextExperience").click(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(".showNextExperience").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div.experience").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).siblingings().eq(0)` should to do it.

Comment: Yes. **INGS** Learn some jQuery why don't you @RUJordan? ;-D

Comment: yeah, it's like your siblings ings

Comment: I hate my sibling's ings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have elements between triggering input and manipulated div:

```
<input class="showNextExperience" >
<p>Hello, new line</p>
<div class="experience">Experience 1</div>

<input class="showNextExperience">
<p>Some text</p>
<div>And an info block</div>
<div class="experience">Experience 2</div>
```

Then you have to use `nextAll` to search not only for the very next element but through the whole DOM, which is probably simpler coding than using `next().find()`:

```
$(".showNextExperience").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".experience").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Does this work if the next element is above the clicked element?