# How to find next div and remove the CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have given below layout

```
    <div id="sampleId1">
     <div class="sam" style="width:10px"> //Here I will remove the width property
      <div class="sam" style="width:50px">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

**Tried code**

```
        var s = $('#sampleId1').find('div').eq(0).attr('class');
        $('.'+s).addClass('example');
        $('.example').css('width', '')
```

After it will be changed like

```
    <div id="sampleId1">
     <div class="sam example" style=""> //It will be affected (line: 1)
      <div class="sam example" style=""> //Here also affected (line: 2)
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Now I wan't to changed in line: 1 only, can any one guide me?

Comment: Try this `$('.sam').first().removeAttr('style')`

Comment: what do you want to change in line one , and which line 1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove css property in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405689/how-to-remove-css-property-in-jquery)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751932/jquery-finding-next-div  For finding next div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this var `$('#sampleId1').find("div").eq(0).addClass("example").css('width','');`

```js
var s = $('#sampleId1').find("div").eq(0).addClass("example").css('width','');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sampleId1">
     <div class="sam" style="width:10px">
      <div class="sam" style="width:50px">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `$('.sam').first().removeAttr('style')`

A snippet showing in action: (view source to see the change)

```js
$('.sam').first().removeAttr('style')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sampleId1">
  <div class="sam" style="width:10px"><!-- this will be changed to <div class="sam"> -->
    <div class="sam" style="width:50px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When You call `var s = $('#sampleId1').find('div').eq(0).attr('class');`

it returns `sam` which is the class of both your divs hence when you

```
$('.'+s).addClass('example');
$('.example').css('width', '')
```

both your divs get changed. If you co`enter code here`uld change the classes for your divs it will work correctly. Else simply use

```
$('#sampleId1').find('div').eq(0).addClass('example');
$('.example').css('width', '');`
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#sampleId1 .sam').first().removeAttr('style').addClass('.example');

console.log($('#sampleId1 .sam')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sampleId1">
     <div class="sam" style="width:10px"> //Here I will remove the width property
      <div class="sam" style="width:50px">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can try this when you want to add class in both div and change css of first div.

```
var s = $('#sampleId1').find('div').eq(0).attr('class');
$('.'+s).addClass('example');
$('#sampleId1').find('div').first().css('width', '');
```